# VBA - How to store .SentOn in excel before sending an email in Outlook

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I have a macro program that sends an email in Outlook. What I want to do is store the date of .SentOn method in Excel after sending the email.

Hope you guys could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SentOn is not set before an email is sent, it is only available after it is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Ok. So, if I want to get the SentOn, I have to look thru the email in Sent Items Folder? Is there a way to set the Date Sent of an Email before sending?

Comment: You can use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder, but again, how can I know when something will be done before it is actually done? If you assume that the message will be set pretty much immediately when you call MailItem.Send, you can use the current time stamp (Now).

Comment: awesome. Thanks @DmitryStreblechenko.